# How to insert VM options into application.properties / application.yml?

Tags: gradle, jvm-arguments

I have application.yml file:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my_db
    username: my_user
    password: password123
```

I want to change this file & insert values by VM options:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: ${dbUrl:jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my_db}
    username: ${dbUser:my_user}
    password: ${dbPassword:password123}
```

With defining these variables with VM options:

```
gradle test --stacktrace -DdbUrl=jdbc:postgresql://postgres-master:5432/another_db \
                         -DdbUser=another_user \
                         -DdbPassword=password456
```

I expect that when these VM options available, it shall replace values in application.yml. But as logs shows, gradle task not find or not recognize these options & fail with stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException at ConstructorResolver.java:800
            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException at ConstructorResolver.java:800
                Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException at ConstructorResolver.java:800
                    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786
                        Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException at JdbcUtils.java:68
                            Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException at ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:303
                                Caused by: java.net.ConnectException at PlainSocketImpl.java:-2
```

How to add values into application.yml with gradle task started?